# For loop in react native

Tags: react-native

I am doing an app in react native and I would like to put inside a view the number of view equal to the number of users I have. But when I save it nothing appears on the screen and it gives me this warning:

*Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a `Component` instead of `<Component />` from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.*

I am using this code (5 as an example number of users):

```js
function setUserViews() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      <View style={styles.userView}>
        <Text>View</Text>
      </View>;
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.background}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => occurenceTreatment()}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Button</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.usersTab}>{() => setUserViews()}</View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default MainScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    backgroundColor: "black",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },

  button: {
    backgroundColor: "#777B7E",
    height: "40%",
    width: "45%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },

  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },

  container: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    flex: 1,
  },

  usersTab: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    flex: 2,
  },

  userView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Can anyone explain me why this says that?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put all items you want to show in an array, a [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) or use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function on the array. An example of using map instead of for loop:

```
function setUserViews() {

const users = [new User(1), new User(3), new User(3), new User(4), new User(5)];

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.background}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => occurenceTreatment()}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Button</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.usersTab}>
      {
        users.map(item, index) => {
          return(
            <View style={styles.userView}>
              <Text>View</Text>
            </View>
          );
        }
      }
    </View>
  </View>
);
}
```

Comment: using your method how does my program know if a new user has signed in? do I need to add it myself to the users array?

Comment: Well, my 'users' array was just a sample of the source of users. You can fetch the users from wherever you want and put them in the array. My answer was just for showing how you can iterate and render an array or a list in React Native

Comment: You're welcome. An upvote will be much appreciated :D